# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser with several identical attributes

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I have this piece of HTML code :

```
                <div class='ipsDataItem_main'>
                    <h4 class='ipsDataItem_title ipsContained_container'>
                                <span>
                                    <a href='https://www.' title='Aller au premier message non lu' data-ipsTooltip>
                                        <span class='ipsItemStatus'><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                        <span class='ipsType_break ipsContained'>
                            <a href='https://www../topic/81272-une-a' class='' title='Une affaire de '  data-ipsHover data-ipsHover-target='https://www/?preview=1' data-ipsHover-timeout='1.5'>
                                <span>
                                    Une affa.    
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </h4>
                    <div class='ipsDataItem_meta ipsType_reset ipsType_light ipsType_blendLinks'>
                        <span>
                            Par 
<a href='https://www../profile/5825-crobler/' data-ipsHover data-ipsHover-target='https://www../profile/5825-cr' title="Aller sur le profil " class="ipsType_break"><span style='color:#0099cc'>Crobler</span></a>,
                        </span><time datetime='2021-03-05T1:5:09Z' title='05/01/2021 20:59 ' data-short='2 j'>Vendredi à 20:59</time>
                        dans <a href="https://www../?fo">WEB-DL 2160</a>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <ul class='ipsTags ipsTags_inline ipsList_inline '>
<li >
    <a href="https://www../tags/une_ails/" class='ipsTag' title="" rel="tag"><span></span></a>
    
</li>
    </ul>   
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I would like to extract title of time tag "05/01/2021 20:59". I tried this following code :

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=ipsDataItem_main] a') as $f) {
     
   echo $f->title;
   
}
```

I have as results all titles but not the one I want. How i can do this please ?
And how i can choose only the "title" i want ? For example title in "ipsType_break ipsContained" class ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `$html->find('.ipsDataItem_meta time')` give the right item?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($html->find('.ipsContained a') as $element) {
       echo $element->title ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a case of getting the right path to find the data you are after...

```
$html->find('.ipsDataItem_meta time')
```